# conditional formatting for newly added rows

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

Ok, I really have no business working in spreadsheets or any data entry program for that matter. So basically what I am saying is I have no idea how to use much of the formula and script/language features. So any help would be AWESOME!

Heres my issue...

I have two Columns, One contains Conditional formatting (Cell Color) for for 3 variables respectfully. The Other Column is a DropDrown with a list.

I'm hoping to avoid explaining to the person(s) here how to keep applying rules as new Rows are added to the end of the sheet.

Is there an a script someone could dig up for me that (I'm guessing onEdit) will automatically apply my Conditional Formatting and DropDowns the new Rows?

Thank you so much!

Comment: can you share an example of the sheet?

Comment: I've been searching all weekend and cannot find a solution. I dont know much about scripting, how to write it and how it even works within the document... Any help you be great ;  )

Comment: Blexy I missed your comment. I will post one up for you.

Comment: Here is a link to a copy of the sheet. If B and G are =<> there are conditions as you will be able to see. I should have a dropdown with a list of shipping methods ie UPS, FedEx, overnight ect... The issue is, the clerks using this sheet... I don't want to have to tell them "when you get low on Rows and add more reapply the conditional formatting and dropdowns..." I just want this to automatically do this when new rows are added. Can you help? Let me know if you need more access to that sheet. Thanks so much!

Comment: [link]https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AqZjzFwBse-sdG9jVk9vLTJ1NWpYV21TS28tRl9EdWc&usp=sharing[link]

Comment: var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var value1Rule1 = ss.getRange('B3:B').getValue();
  var value2Rule1 = ss.getRange('G3:G').getValue();
  var range3Rule1 = ss.getRange('H3:H');
  var color1 = '#00ff00';
  var color2 = '#00ffff';
  var color3 = '#ffff00';
if (value1Rule1 == value2Rule1) range3Rule1.setBackgroundColor(color1);
if (value1Rule1 > value2Rule1) range3Rule1.setBackgroundColor(color2);
if (value1Rule1 < value2Rule1) range3Rule1.setBackgroundColor(color3);
if (value1Rule1 = "") range3Rule1.setBackgroundColor(white)

Comment: Ive made it this far, The script is working but unfortunately its coloring the entire Column H. It also seems to be dependent on Row3, I need to to just compare b3-g3>color h3 b4-g4> color h4

Comment: Could you give me edit permissions to the script? Also, could you paste your code in the comments into the question and format it? Hard to read.

Comment: Ok, You should be able to edit. I have another script working and its going line for line, but I cannot figure out how to get the blank cells to be white. and IDK why but this editor will not let me paste in code...

Comment: Im in the doc with you if you want to open chat

Comment: I pasted my script in the script manager called Formatting

Comment: I figured the solution out. Im not sure if its 100% the best way to it but its working.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this would ever receive another answer so, for the moment considering only `I need to to just compare b3-g3>color h3 b4-g4> color h41`:

In New Google Sheets, apply your formula to H2:-

```
=arrayformula(if(G2:G=0,"",if(B2:B=G2:G,"Completed",IF(B2:B>G2:G,"Back Ordered",if(B2:B<G2:G,"Over Shipped")))))
```

and rules like these in Conditional formatting...:

[image: SO19871471 example]

and I think as new rows are added and data populated in A:G the formulae (both `if` and Conditional) extend automatically, with no fill where the cell in Column G is `0` or empty.